# What is regex for alphanumeric with no spaces?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match this like:

```
1. 1234           true
2. 1234 5678      false
3. 1234x          true
4. x1234          true
5. abcd           false
6. abcd 1234      false
```

so I need to match just a string with numbers only or numbers and characters only and with no spaces (single word).
This doesn't really work:

```
/([0-9])\w+/g
```

Comment: Add the start and end so it is not just matching that anywhere in the string.

Comment: In your examples all the digits are contiguous and all the letters are contiguous. Is that required? For example, what about `"1a2"`? Also, according to your spec, `"1234x y"` is not to be matched. Is that correct?

Comment: 1a2 should pass. "1234x y" should not.. But it's already answered below
/(^[\da-z]*(?!\s)\d+[a-z]*$)/g
thank you

Comment: Try: `^[^\W_]*\d+[^\W_]*$`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
/(^[\da-z]*(?!\s)\d+[a-z]*$)/g
```

[Regex Tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NMlE.png)

Comment: Okay, but the `(?!\s)` is completely pointless, the first `\d` should be moved into the `[a-z]` near the end of the regex, and there is no need for the surrounding `()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern `([0-9])\w+` is unanchored, so it can have partial matches.

It also has to start with a digit, and at least 1 word character, have the string to be at least 2 characters long.

---

You can use anchors, and make sure to match a single digit. For a match only, you can omit the capture group:

```
^[^\W\d]*\d\w*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\W\d]*` Optionally match any word character except a digit
- `\d` Match a single digit
- `\w*` Match optional word characters
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xu9eiq/1)

**Note** that `\w` can also match `_`

Comment: One way to match a letter or digit (works in Javascript, Ruby, perhaps others) is `[\w&&[^_]]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Hi Cary, yes that is the character class subtraction right? This would also work `^[^\W\d_]*\d[^\W_]*$`

Comment: ...and works in PCRE and Python. `&&` takes the intersection of matches of `\w` and `[^_]`, or, as you say, the matches of `\w` that do not match `[^_]`.

Answer (score 1):

Match the entire string and require a at least one digit:

```js
/^[a-z]*[0-9][a-z0-9]*$/i
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/ZlkR6U/1/). **Important**: `i` flag (case insensitive).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z]*                   any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z0-9]*                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9'
                           (0 or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        the end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const strings = ['1234','12x3', '12 X'];
console.log(strings.filter(string=> string.match(/^[0-9a-z]+$/i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

regex: `/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/`

use `test` to get boolean result; use `match` to get matched string

```js
const result = ['1234', '1234 5678', '1234x', 'x1234', 'abcd', 'abcd 1234'].map(str=> /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/.test(str))
console.log(result)
```